# Grails: Setting datasource bean in applicationcontext in unit Tests

Tags: junit, applicationcontext, grails3

I am using grails 3.2.7 & 
I am unit Testing a method that has following lines of code:

```
void abc(){
ApplicationContext ctx = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext
def dataSource = ctx.getBean('dataSource')
}
```

Inside unit test(JUnit) can anyone please help me with : **How to set 'datasource' Bean in applicationContext?**

I tried:

```
applicationContext.beanFactory.registerSingleton("dataSource", DataSource)
```

But this doesn't work.
Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution is:

Inside the Junit Test class:

```
Class TestCl {
    DataSource dataSource

      @Before
      public void setup() {
        defineBeans {
          def bb = new BeanBuilder()
          bb.beans {
            dataSource(BasicDataSource)
          }
        }
        applicationContext.beanFactory.registerSingleton("dataSource", dataSource)
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting through application Context, I would suggest using Dependency Injection to get dataSource Bean.

You can do the following:

```
Class SampleService {
   def dataSource

   def abc(){
     //do the thing with the dataSource!
   }
}
```

Also, I think you need Integration Test instead of Unit test to actually test persistence logic.
[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946715/testing-service-with-sql-and-datasource)